# How to store a mutable borrow with a specified lifetime in an enum?

Tags: rust, enums, lifetime, borrow-checker

I want to be able to store a mutable borrow `&mut Foo<'a>` inside an enum variant. I can work with the mutable borrow directly just fine, but not with an enum containing the mutable borrow. Extract of simplified code below ('full' playground version with 'broken' code commented out [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=86791119830adf5c019bd503b0515a57)).

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    shared_ref: &'a usize,
    child_foos: HashMap<usize, Foo<'a>>,
}
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    
    // Get a 'naked' mutable reference to the child foo - works fine!
    pub fn get_handle(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Foo<'a> {
        self.child_foos.get_mut(&id).unwrap()
    }

    // !!! Get an 'enclosed' mutable reference to the child foo - doesn't work !!!
    pub fn get_handle_in_enum(&mut self, id: usize) -> Handle {
        Handle::Foo(self.child_foos.get_mut(&id).unwrap())
    }
}

// Note: Compiler demands &'a mut Foo<'a>. Q: why is the &'a mut needed 
// (i.e. why can't it be &mut Foo<'a>)?
enum Handle<'a> {
    Foo(&'a mut Foo<'a>),
}
```

First question: Why am I forced to use `&'a mut Foo<'a>` in the enum definition (I would like to be able to use `&mut Foo<'a>` instead). I'm sure there is a good reason, but I suspect that this is responsible for the resulting compiler errors.

Second question: When I compile the code I some very confusing errors, including one where the compiler says it found what it was expecting?!

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:39:9
   |
39 |         Handle::Foo(self.child_foos.get_mut(&id).unwrap())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:38:31
   |
38 |     pub fn get_handle_in_enum(&mut self, id: usize) -> Handle {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/main.rs:39:9
   |
39 |         Handle::Foo(self.child_foos.get_mut(&id).unwrap())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Handle<'_>`
              found `Handle<'_>`
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:30:6
   |
30 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:39:21
   |
39 |         Handle::Foo(self.child_foos.get_mut(&id).unwrap())
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut Foo<'_>`
              found `&mut Foo<'a>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
error: could not compile `enum_mut_borrow` due to previous error
```

Any explanation or suggestions for how to use enums properly in this situation would be hugely appreciated (in my real code I need more variants of the enum each with its own mutable borrow)!

Comment: Does this answer your question [Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope?](/q/66252831/2189130) If not that directly, perhaps one of the linked questions. Basically `&'a mut Foo<'a>` is almost always wrong.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for the link - I was aware that `&'a mut Foo<'a>` was likely cause issues so I was trying to avoid it. It was just that this was the compiler's fairly insistent suggestion (I should have been more sceptical!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not forced to put `&'a mut Foo<'a>`. You are forced to have an **explicit lifetime**: all borrows (exclusive or not) have an associated lifetime, but most of the time Rust doesn't require you to explicitly write it. Type definition doesn't fall in that category, so you need to explicitly write it:

```rust
enum Handle<'a, 'b> {
    Foo(&'b mut Foo<'a>),
}
```

this way, you dissociate the borrow's lifetime from `Foo`'s.

To make this work, you also need to explicitly name the lifetime of `&mut self` in `get_handle_in_enum`:

```rust
fn get_handle_in_enum<'b>(&'b mut self, id: usize) -> Handle<'a, 'b> {
    ...
}
```

See the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87246973b3b9b39fab60e8d015e18983).

Comment: Exceptionally helpful answer - many thanks! Was not expecting to need multiple lifetimes, but it makes sense. I think I read too much into the compiler's suggestion to use `&'a mut Foo<'a>` in the enum definition and just ran with it.

Comment: @tokoloshe countrary to most other aspects of the compiler, is not smart at all when it comes to lifetimes. It doesn't try to "make them work" or anything, it just has a preset of simple rules that allow implicit lifetimes, and a couple of error messages that reuse existing lifetimes when possible and that's it. Usually, it's not a good idea to follow its indication (for lifetimes) if these indications don't make it work right away, because the situation is probably too complex for these simple rules.